# Issues with Google maps scraping using R

Tags: web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to learn web scraping by scraping average google reviews and addresses on google maps. But I have a few questions that I hope to get help on:

1. Missing reviews, making date difficult to match

This company has 6 outlets. But only 5 has reviews.

[Google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ryB0.jpg)

So when I run the following code to extract the name of the outlet and ratings, I get 6 names and 5 ratings data. So I am unable to match the name of the outlet to the ratings

[Name result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Uww.png)
[Rating result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udMaK.png)

The issue is because the outlet with no reviews does not have a class for the aria-label for my code to work.

[Inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiYnf.png)

Is it possible for me to extract the information in such a way that I can match the rating to the review?

```
pacman::p_load(rvest,
               xml2,
               RSelenium)

rmDr=rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port=4443L)$client
myclient= rmDr
myclient$navigate("https://www.google.com/maps/search/attea/@1.3586881,103.8165833,12z/data=!3m1!4b1")

html_obj <- myclient$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>% read_html()

names <- html_obj %>% html_elements(".hfpxzc")%>% 
  html_attr("aria-label") 

name_outlet<-as.data.frame(names)

stars_numrev <- html_obj %>% html_elements(".ZkP5Je")%>% 
  html_attr("aria-label") 

stars_numrev_outlet<-as.data.frame(stars_numrev)
```

2. The second issue I have is that I am trying to extract the address as well, but I am again unable to extract the text without aria-label and class.

[Element example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Xuc.png)

3. Last question, how do I get the side bar to scroll to the bottom? I can't use rselenium to send key presses. Would I be able to simulate hovering the mouse of the side bar and simulate mouse scrolling?

Sorry for the long list of questions. I have been interested in scraping for a long time and I have been learning primarily from web sources. Any help or directions to useful guides will be deeply appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Oh I think I have solved the first question, instead of extracting the aria-label, I go to the class that contains the text and extract the text using html_text instead.

`stars_numrev <- html_obj %>% html_elements(".AJB7ye")%>% 
  html_text()`

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For your example, I was able to pull the address using this:

```
html_obj %>% 
  html_node("div.RcCsl:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1)") %>%
  html_text()
```

```
[1] "2500 Chestnut Ave, Glenview, IL 60026"
```

I tried it with a few different locations so it seems to be reasonably robust. The class name `.Io6YTe` appears to also be the same for different locations, so that would probably also work as an html node. You may need to add a step to wait for the page to load before pulling the html from the page.

I'm still working on question 3, I'll edit this answer if I figure anything out. What's the end goal for scrolling to the bottom? Maybe there's an alternative way to reach that goal?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will give it a try. I figured one way to solve question 3, which is included in my edits above. The purpose is to make sure that all the possible listings are loaded before I scrape the information.